# C# Winforms Region.IsVisible

Tags: c#, winforms, point, region

I want to detect mouse click on my custom created region.

1) I ve tried this  code with rectangle and it worked, but with string it doesnt

```
 GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    Region reg = new Region();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        gp.AddString("TEXT", new FontFamily("Arial"),0, 20.0f, new Point(300, 10), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        gp.Widen(Pens.AliceBlue);
        reg = new Region(gp);
    }
```

and here is the part2

```
  private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (reg.IsVisible(e.Location))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("aaaa");
        }
    }
```

It doesnt show the message box. :)

EDIT :here is my Paint event to see where my string is

```
 private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        e.Graphics.DrawString("TEXT", new Font("Arial", 20), Brushes.Yellow, 300,100 );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic error is a typo: One time you draw at `y = 10`, the other time at `y = 100`.

But there is another issue which is not so obvious at all:

Add

```
e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Firebrick, gp);
```

to the `Paint` event and you'll see it: The fonts have quite a different size.

That is because when adding text to a `GraphicsPath` it is using a different scale (called *'emSize'*) than `Graphics.DrawString` does, which uses  *'Point'*.

To adapt you can use this:

```
float fontsize = 20.0f;
using (Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics()) fontsize *= g.DpiY / 72f;
```

Now you can build the `GraphicsPath`, best with the correct coordinates..:

```
gp.AddString("TEXT", new FontFamily("Arial"), 0, fontsize, 
             new Point(300, 100), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
```

Comment: All in your own good time ;-) - Btw, you don't need a region for this as GraphicsPath also has an IsVisible method..