# PrintDocument baseline printing and line spacing

Tags: c#, label, drawstring, printdocument

I have an app that prints very small labels.

One thing I have noticed is that the printing (using DrawString with a rectangle) aligns text based on the TOP of the font ascender size.  So when there are 2 font sizes on a line, you get this.
[image: Top Alignment Issue]

The PrintDocument object apparently has no ability to do line spacing or vertical alignment.

In other words I guess I need to calculate all that myself.

My main question is:

Is there *another object* I should be using where I can align text on the baseline, and "tighten" the vertical spacing to prevent my content from overrunning the labels?  You know, like Word and LibreOffice?

[image: Libre Office Paragraph Settings]

Or do I have to reverse engineer it all in my code.

Comment: It is not really an aspect of `PrintDocument` as it is just the "document" holder, its more related to `DrawString ` which has multiple layout and formatting options beyond the layout rect.  You should post your code so we can see what the starting point is

Comment: The notes here: [Properly draw text using Graphics Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074638/7444103) and here: [I want to remove padding from top and bottom (...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383828/7444103) may help.

Comment: You will ned to calculate the baseline offset. There are posts that decribe how to do that..

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answers.  Any opinions on using the FixedDocument and FlowDocument objects?