# Graphics.DrawString method is not drawing text from upper left corner

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have a little problem. `Graphics.DrawString` method is not drawing text from upper left corner but fewer pixels under and few pixels more on right side then it schould.
There is my code:

```
graphics.DrawString("TeSt", new Font("Arial", sizeOfFont), blackOne.Brush, 0, 0);
```

and there is a result:

[image]

How can u see text is shifted few pixels down and right when rectangle behind "TeSt" is drawn correctly from (0, 0) point. I tried everything and there is my question. Did i missed somethink or just it is like it is, if so then why?

Comment: Do you have any active _[transforms?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-the-world-transformation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)_.   Try performing a `graphics.Transform = new Matrix()`

Comment: That's the default padding. It's fully applied when you specify a Point instead of a Rectangle and no StringFormat options to position the Text. Defining the text position as *fewer pixels under and few pixels more on right side than it should* is not correct: the text is drawn exactly how you asked.  -- If you're drawing on a Bitmap, I suggest this method: [Remove top and bottom padding from Text drawn on an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383828/7444103). Otherwise, you need to describe the actual *canvas*.

Comment: If you're drawing on a Control's surface (or Items of a list presenter, as ListBox, ListView etc.), prefer `TextRenderer.DrawText()` to `Graphics.DrawString()`. Specify the `TextFormatFlags` needed to draw the text as you want it to be.