# Why DrawString not start at (0,0) position?

Tags: c#, winforms

when draw string into image by code :

```
g.DrawString("99", font, new SolidBrush(FontColorPnl.BackColor), 0,0);
```

The string does not start from the point (0,0) as shown in the picture

[image]
how can start drawing from point(0,0)

Comment: What is that image representing? Are you drawing text directly on a Bitmap, or a Control that is showing the Bitmap? If you're drawing onto a Bitmap, you probably have not set flags that remove the default padding

Comment: @Jimi drawing text directly on a Bitmap

Comment: See the example here: [Remove top and bottom padding from Text drawn on an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383828/7444103). It's just one method. You can also use TextRenderer

Comment: Could also be useful: [How to compute the correct width of a digit in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54772134/7444103) -- [Properly draw text using GraphicsPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074638/7444103)