# TextBox with dotted lines for typing

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a dotted lines that is used as input for typing text on it instead using a text box.
For example:
Instead of text box:
[image: Text Box]

I want to make something like this:

[image: Dotted lines]

and to be able to type on it.

Comment: Are those dotted lines inside the textbox?  Like if you press "A", it replaces one of the dashes?  Or are the dashes like an underline?

Comment: I don't want to have the borders of the textbox, I want to have just the dotted lines like an underline and to be able to type on it

Comment: Put a borderless TextBox inside a Panel (or UserControl) and draw your dotted line in the paint event of that Panel (or UserControl).

Comment: @LabinotAziri did you do any research? there are lots of resources of how to use the paint events of a control

Answer (score 1):

In the Paint event of a panel that is hosting a borderless TextBox control, you can draw it like this:

```
private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black)) {
    p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(textBox1.Left, textBox1.Bottom + 2),
                           new Point(textBox1.Right, textBox1.Bottom + 2));
  }
}
```

Ends up looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a Custom Control derived from TextBox.
Overriding its WndProc and handling [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint), you can draw a dotted/dashed line (or anything else) inside the edit control's ClientArea. Then refresh the line drawing when keys are pressed, so the line is not erased.

`WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_CAPTURECHANGED` are also handled, since these can (will) cause the painting of the background.

The position of the base line is calculated using the [FontFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily)'s [GetLineSpacing()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily.getlinespacing) and [GetCellAscent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontfamily.getcellascent) methods, then *moved down* the size of the Pen used to draw the line.
[OnFontChanged()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.onfontchanged) is overridden to get a notification when the Font changes.

Some more info here:  [Properly draw text using Graphics Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074638/7444103)

It's a little *raw*, but see how it goes :)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ToolboxItem(true)]
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class TextBoxBaseline : TextBox
{
    private const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private const int WM_CAPTURECHANGED = 0x0215;

    private float m_lnSpacing = 0.0f;
    private float m_cellAscent = 0.0f;

    public TextBoxBaseline() {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnFontChanged(e);
        m_lnSpacing = Font.FontFamily.GetLineSpacing(Font.Style);
        m_cellAscent = Font.FontFamily.GetCellAscent(Font.Style);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_PAINT:
                using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DimGray, 1)) {
                    pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
                    int baseLine = (int)(Font.GetHeight(g) * m_cellAscent / m_lnSpacing + pen.Width);
                    g.DrawLine(pen, 1, baseLine, ClientSize.Width - 1, baseLine);
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                }
                break;
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            case WM_CAPTURECHANGED:
                this.Invalidate();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: TextBox Baseline]  [image: TextBox Baseline dark]  [image: TextBox Baseline light]

---

If you don't know how to used this code:

- Add a new class to your Project and name it `TextBoxBaseline`.
- Copy the `using` directives you find here and paste them on top of the class.
- Copy the rest of the code and replace the default class definition in your class file, without removing the namespace.
- Build the Project.
- You'll find the `TextBoxBaseline` Control in the ToolBox. Open up a Form and drop it on it as usual.