# Size of GraphicsPath drawing?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, gdi+

I'm working on a program that allows using a bitmap (in a PictureBox) as a text object.  I have things mostly working, even word-wrap, all except for outlined text.

```
private void DrawOutlineString(string text, PointF pos)
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    SolidBrush b = new(forecolor);
    Pen pen = new(outlinecolor, outlinesize);
    Pen p = pen;
    GraphicsPath gp = new();
    gp.AddString(text, fontfamily, (int)fontstyle, g.DpiY 
        * fontsize / 72, pos, new StringFormat());
    g.DrawPath(p, gp);
    g.FillPath(b, gp);
    gp.Dispose();
    p.Dispose();
    b.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
}
```

For outlined text, I'm using a `GraphicsPath` object and adding the string with font info to it, then using `DrawPath` and then `FillPath` to draw it.

Note that `DrawPath` uses a pen and the pen's thickness determines how thick the outline is.

The problem is that the size of the text put to the bitmap that way is not the same as the size it would be with a `DrawString`.  But it is not the same as simply adding the outline size to the `g.MeasureString` result.

```
private SizeF GetTextSize(string text)
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
    g.Dispose();
    return size;
}

private SizeF GetOutlineTextSize(string text)
{
    SizeF size = GetTextSize(text);
    size.Width += outlinesize * 2;
    size.Height += outlinesize * 2;
    return size;
}
```

I've tried adding the outline size (as defined in my pen) to the `g.MeasureString` size and I've tried doubling the outline size (since once on each side), but no such luck.  Help!

Okay, after a cursory examination of the link provided by Jimi, here is my latest attempt:

```
        private SizeF GetOutlineTextSize(string text)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        Pen p = new Pen(outlinecolor, outlinesize);
        GraphicsPath gp = new();
        gp.AddString(text, fontfamily, (int)fontstyle, g.DpiY * fontsize / 72, position, new StringFormat());
        RectangleF rect = gp.GetBounds(null, p);
        gp.Dispose();
        p.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
        SizeF size = new(rect.Width, rect.Height);
        return size;
    }
```

I haven't had a chance to fully test this method yet, but it looks hopeful.

Comment: Consider either removing the "guys" at the start of your post (it adds nothing to the content of your post and is exclusionary), or, at the very least, changing it to "Folks"

Comment: Actually, that was originally "Hi, guys!", but for some reason got clipped.  ??  But, yeah, ...  Hi, Folks!  ;')

Comment: Just a guess: Fluffy salutations like "Hi" are frowned on on this site (they add no content. It could be that the site strips of the "Hi" you apparently started your post with

Comment: Some actual code would be useful

Comment: [Properly draw text using GraphicsPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074638/7444103)

Comment: Okay, added some of the code for the internal helper functions.

Comment: Thanks, Jimi.  It looks pretty complicated to me, but I will study through it and maybe my answer is in there.

Comment: Okay, I came up with a simplified function and edited my question to show it.  If it turns out to be my answer, it's all thanks to Jimi for pointing me at it.  ;')

Comment: You should be using `using()` blocks for all of those GDI objects instead of manually calling `.Dispose()` - otherwise if an exception is thrown then you'll leak GDI resources.