# Calc text width, JS vs Windows graphics

Tags: c#, .net-core, fonts, gdi, system.drawing

I have this code in JS:

```js
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
     const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     context.font = font;
     return context.measureText(text).width;
 }

const myWidth = getTextWidth("Hello", "12px Arial");
// returns 27.345703125
```

Now, I'm trying to implement the same in C#.

```cs
public static double CalcTextWidth(string text, string fontName, float fontSize)
{
    Font font =  new (fontName, fontSize);
        
    using Bitmap bitmap = new(1, 1);
    using Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(text, font);

    return size.Width;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var width =  CalcTextWidth("Hello", "Arial", 12);
// returns 42.88
```

How can I adjust the .NET result with JS result?

Comment: Replace `Graphics.MeasureString()` with `TextRenderer.MeasureText()`. It uses the Screen DC if no `IDeviceContext` is specified. The result depends on how the current Screen is scaled. Based on the syntax your code is using, I assume the DpiAwareness is set to SystemAware, if you haven't changed it

Comment: @Jimi "the name TextRenderer doesn't exists". I'm using .NET 8 console application.

Comment: `TextRenderer` is in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. You tagged the question `[winforms]`

Comment: @Jimi, Sorry! You are right! I replaced the tag with `.net-core`.

Comment: It doesn't change much. It's just a different assembly. Why are you trying to match an abstract pixel size to a pixel size that refers to the logical Screen scale? Is it about printing stuff?

Comment: Because it's not for screen but for print. I need to create a PDF sticker with 500mm width. I need to calculate if the sticker can contain a text (that is the user input) in specific font. If no, I have to create another sticker.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there. The description and what comes out in comments are quite vague. Note that the canvas created like that is not exactly a surface for printing. Also, note that usually Fonts in GDI+ / GDI are measured in `Ems` (see the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074638/7444103)), so you may want to specify `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` if you require measures in pixels. Build the Font as, e.g. `var font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`. Also, the Font is subject to scaling. The two contexts may not match exactly anyway

Comment: As a side note, when you measure text with either TextRenderer of the Graphics object (strictly related to a DC), you need to specify format flags that remove any padding, since the rendered text in GDI+ / GDI is always padded. TextRenderer respects the `TextRenderingHint` specified in any Graphics context (defaults to ClearType, which is related to System screen settings, i.e., not generally suited to printing)

Comment: @Jimi, I read all your comments. I don't have a good answer. I just know what I need: a dotnet core method that will give me the same result like the JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the same result you must:

- Change the Graphics [PageUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit) to [Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphicsunit) (by default it's Display)
- Change the GDI+ (System.Drawing) string format to [GenericTypographic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.generictypographic) which is usually better for interoperability with other systems.

So for example this code should give you the same value:

```
public static double CalcTextWidth(string text, string fontName, float fontSize)
{
    Font font = new(fontName, fontSize);

    using Bitmap bitmap = new(1, 1);
    using Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;
    SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(text, font, int.MaxValue, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    return size.Width;
}
```